# Sorting coordinates and keep the lowest value

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, matrix, coordinates

For the array below, I am interested to sort the X-axis according to the y-axis and record the lowest tuple of the lowest X-value.

The array is:

```
A = [(537, 14),
     (537, 12),
     (538, 13),
     (538, 14), # (538, 14) should be removed and (537, 14) should be kept
     (539, 12),
     (709, 9)]
```

I would to do this:

```
New_A = [(537, 14),
         (537, 12),
         (538, 13), 
         (539, 12),
         (709, 9)]
```

What could I try here?

Comment: Can you explain why `(537,14)` but `(538,13)`? Shouldn't it be `(537,12)` as you mentioned lowest?

Comment: Apologies, typo mistake! I apologize for the confusion. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given:

```
a = [(537, 14),
     (537, 12),
     (538, 13),
     (538, 14),
     (539, 12),
     (709, 9)]
```

you can do:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

f = itemgetter(1)
new_a = [next(group) for _, group in groupby(sorted(a, key=f, reverse=True), key=f)]
```

which gives:

```
[(537, 14), 
 (538, 13), # <- I am assuming you have a typo here OP
 (537, 12), 
 (709, 9)]
```

- Here is a link to find out more about [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).
- And here is another one for [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to groupby, works perfectly :)

Comment: You have repeated `537` in output.

Comment: @bro-grammer The way I understood the (not entirely clear) question is to keep the tuple `x` that for the same `x[1]` has the lowest `x[0]`. And OP said that *"..it works perfectly"*. Do you understand it differently?

Comment: I don't understand the question at all. I thought `New_A` is the required output.

Comment: @bro-grammer It is, but it contradicts the text explaining how to get to it.

Comment: Apologies, corrected the question. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

To sort your list, use

```
New_A = sorted(A, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

A common pattern is to sort complex objects using some of the object's indices as a key.

The second part of your question.

To get the lowest value according to X, and lowest value according to y are both shown below

```
lowest = New_A[0]
print(lowest)
(537, 14)

lowest = New_A[-1]
print(lowest)
(709, 9)
```

Answer (score 1):

The given two dimensional array is :

```
A = [(537, 14),  (537, 12),  (538, 13),  (538, 14),  (539, 12), (709, 9)]
```

Let us suppose `A` is a relation with `(x,y)` as ordered pairs.
Therefore declare two variables `x` and `y` and initialize them to the first values, i.e,

```
x=537 and y=14
```

Hence

```
x=A[0][0]
y=A[0][1]
```

Also take two dummy variables `i` and `j` to iterate through the two dimensional array : 
The following algorithm chooses the lowest `x` value. If there are more than 1 `x` values which are equal , then choose `(x,y)` such that `y` is lowest.

```
# Here it starts :

j=0
for i in range(1,len(A)):
    for j in range(0,1) :
        if A[i][j]<x :
            x=A[i][0]
            y=A[i][1]
        elif x==A[i][0] and y>A[i][1] :
            y=A[i][1]
ans=(x,y)        

print(ans)
```

The ordered pair (x,y) is stored in the variable `ans` and then printed.
Please let me know if there is change in algorithm's logic.